# css, when you vertically center inline-block elements

Tags: css, centering

I'm trying to center `inline-block vertically and horizontally.`

I read articles about **ghost-element trick.**

To put **ghost-element**, i used **psue-do class** and `height:100%;`

tried it though, i don't think it perfectly makes it.

It is a little bit off to right !
and gave it a negative margin
 in order to perfect center it.

I figured if you give it

```
margin-left:-5.5px;
```

it's done !!

Now, I'm curious where **-5.5px** comes from
or if i'm wrong, please correct me

Thanks

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You could always use `Flexbox` that is a great solution for this kind of cases and little pain to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
}

.container {

  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  &:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}

.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: initial;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #FF5252;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="centered">
    I am centered
  </div>
</div>
```